# Cannot assign boolean value to a variable in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have `$weMountedBoot` set to false like this in the beginning of my script:

```
weMountedBoot=false
```

Now if it isn't mounted, and thus the conditional code runs I get this error and the variable is **not** set to true:

```
./verifyBootFiles: line 41: false=true: command not found
```

relevant code:

```
if ! mount | grep "/boot" > /dev/null

   then

      sudo mount -r -U $toCheck $mountPoint
      $weMountedBoot=true

   fi
```

What's wrong? As you probably figured I really like shell scripting and have loads of experience... so any other remarks about the code are also welcome.

Comment: Remember to upvote and choose the best answer. Regards.

Comment: unfortunately upvoting requires 15 rep... but I'll remember...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the leading `$`.

`$weMountedBoot=true` will be `weMountedBoot=true`.